# Combine Multiple Records in single record

Tags: sql, vb.net, reporting-services, rdlc

actually i have query that contains

tbl 1 : product details
tbl 2 : product company details

when i make a query, for each item record repeat the company details and that's make a duplicates records

all i want to find a way to combine all item for their company without repeating

```
SELECT 
     tbl_item.item_Number, 
     tbl_item.item_Number_Description, 
     tbl_Models.Model_Name, 
     tbl_Companies.Com_Name 
FROM tbl_Companies 
INNER JOIN (tbl_Models 
            INNER JOIN tbl_item 
              ON tbl_Models.Mod_ID = tbl_item.item_Model) 
   ON tbl_Companies.Com_ID = tbl_Models.Model_Company;
```

Comment: Show the query, the result, and the desired result.

Comment: here is the Query , SELECT tbl_item.item_Number, tbl_item.item_Number_Description, tbl_Models.Model_Name, tbl_Companies.Com_Name
FROM tbl_Companies INNER JOIN (tbl_Models INNER JOIN tbl_item ON tbl_Models.Mod_ID = tbl_item.item_Model) ON tbl_Companies.Com_ID = tbl_Models.Model_Company;

Comment: the result item1   model1  company1 , item2 model2 company 1 i want to combine company fields to be single record for all same company items

Comment: @AhmedElgammal Is better Edit your question instead of put code in the comment

Comment: Also show us your sample data and desire result, that would help a lot to understand your question. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You also could us a [**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/256da/8)

Comment: @AhmedElgammal, also realize the design of the report need not mirror the shape of the query result.